# 嘘ついてたんだ vs 嘘ついたんだ

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I saw this being said in a drama, when A said to B, 嘘ついてたんだ and the translation was "So you lied!".

My question is, why is it 嘘ついてたんだ and not 嘘ついたんだ? 
Thanks.

Edit: How to tell the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5):

When someone says 「[嘘]{うそ}ついたんだ。」, s/he is talking about the act which is saying something untrue.

When someone says 「嘘つい**て**たんだ。」,  s/he is talking about the acts which are saying something untrue and keeping it secret for a period of time.

In many cases, 嘘つい**て**たんだ sounds more guilty than 嘘ついたんだ, although it depends on the context.

Comment: Thanks for differentiating between the two, while one is an act and the other are acts over a period of time. That sure erased away my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

嘘をついてたんだ is short for 嘘をついていたんだ.  They're using the ている-form which is used for verbs in progress, similar to the english -ing though not exactly the same. Instead of "you lied" (嘘をついた） the meaning becomes "you were lying" or "you've been lying" (all this time)（嘘をついてた）.

Comment: Not that simple.  It is more like "had been lying" or "had lied" vs. a plain  "lied".  Tenses do not match up very nicely between the two languages.

Comment: I'll try to nuance it a bit. thanx :)

Comment: 「嘘ついてたんだ。」って言われたら、「騙してたの！？」I've been cheated? て思うかな・・・

Comment: 簡単な説明だけど、よく分りました。ありがとう